# Are there lattice waves/vibrational modes in materiels at room temperature and above?

Tags: waves, vibrations

The following excerpt is from: http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Lattice+Vibrations

> 'At room temperature and above, most of the thermal energy resides in the waves of highest frequency. Because of the short wavelength, the motion of neighboring atoms is essentially uncorrelated, so that for many purposes the vibrations can be regarded as those of independently vibrating atoms, each moving about its average position in three dimensions with average vibrational energy of 3kT, where k is the Boltzmann constant and T the absolute temperature. The wave character of the vibrations is needed, however, to describe heat transport by lattice waves.'

Is an amorphous (non-crystalline) material being described here? Or, do you believe they are describing a crystalline material, with a lattice, that has just short wavelengths?

If it's the latter, that would seem like a contradiction to say 'lattice' and 'short wavelengths', together, as periodic motion is what's needed for lattice waves/vibrational modes, correct?

Comment: The technical term for these vibrations is "phonons" and they occur in crystalline as well as amorphous solids. The lowest energies in the phonon spectrum are so low that one has to go to very low temperatures to observe them individually, even though the typical resonance frequencies of these vibrations are in the GHz-THz range. Phonons can also be imaged with quite "pleasing" results: http://www.scielo.org.za/scielo.php?pid=S0038-23532008000500011&script=sci_arttext

Comment: Hey @CuriousOne, how come you comment so much but don't post as answers. Seems like you could totally close this one out.

Comment: @DanielSank: I am feeling too tired to write a better answer about phonons right now... and I have some bad memories of my solid state physics exam.

Comment: @CuriousOne Aye, I hear that. Solid state physics was the worst course I took in college.

Comment: @DanielSank: It's kind of sad, though. I think solid state physics provides a lot of great toy systems for more fundamental physics and I wish they would make the teaching of it more interesting.

Comment: @CuriousOne Agreed.

Comment: @CuriousOne great link with fascinating images

Comment: @CuriousOne are random (thermal) lattice vibrations the same thing as 'independent modes'? If not, what are random/thermal atomic vibrations?